Hard Voting Classifier: What happens in case of a tie (sklearn)
I have 9 different models for a classification problem with three possible outputs. I want to do VotingClassifier with a hard voting mechanism.
Sounds easy, just count how often which class is predicted. But if I want to use the function instead of programming it myself, what happens by a tie?
For example:

1x class 0
4x class 1
4x class 2

I tried to find some pattern but no chance. It is not ascending or something else, it looks random. Is there a possibility, that when a tie happens, I can say "use class 4"?
I trid already to figure out some pattern, without success..

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The "first" class (using python's sort order, so alphabetically for string classes) among the ties is the final prediction. From the User Guide:

In the cases of a tie, the VotingClassifier will select the class based on the ascending sort order.  E.g., in the following scenario

classifier 1 -> class 2

classifier 2 -> class 1


the class label 1 will be assigned to the sample.


is there a possibility to change that rule? So that I can choose what class in case of a tie?

You can't override the behavior of .predict, no.  You can use .transform instead, which for hard-voting will return the array of the of predictions of all the underlying classifiers, and then post-process that.  https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier.transform
